# Learning JavaScript - calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm learning JavaScript and as a start I'm trying to create a calculator.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var numbers = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  var result = document.querySelectorAll('.result')[0];
  var clear = document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    if (numbers[i].innerHTML === '=') {
      numbers[i].addEventListener("click", calculate(i));
    } else {
      numbers[i].addEventListener("click", addValue(i));
    }
  }

  clear.onclick = function() {
    result.innerHTML = '';
  };


  function addValue(i) {
    return function() {
      if (numbers[i].innerHTML === '÷') {
        result.innerHTML += '/';
      } else if (numbers[i].innerHTML === 'x') {
        result.innerHTML += '*';
      } else {
        result.innerHTML += numbers[i].innerHTML;
      }
    };
  }

  function calculate(i) {
    return function() {
      result.innerHTML = eval(result.innerHTML);
    };
  }
};
```

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font: bold 15px Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 #calculator {
   width: 312px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 100px auto;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   background: #0088cc;
 }
 .top span.clear {
   float: left;
 }
 .top .result {
   height: 40px;
   width: 212px;
   float: left;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   border-radius: 3px;
   font-size: 17px;
   line-height: 40px;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   text-align: right;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 .keys,
 .top {
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .keys span,
 .top span.clear {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   width: 66px;
   height: 36px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 3px;
   margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
   line-height: 36px;
   text-align: center;
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
 }
 span.equ {
   background: #00FF19;
 }
 .top span.clear {
   background: red;
   color: white;
   font-size: 17px;
 }
 .keys span:active {
   top: 3px;
 }
 .top span.clear:active {
   top: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div class="top">
    <span class="clear">C</span>
    <div class="result"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="keys">
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>+</span>

    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>-</span>

    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>÷</span>

    <span>0</span>
    <span>.</span>
    <span class="equ">=</span>
    <span>x</span>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: bold 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

You should avoid the `*` if possible. The issue with `*` is that it affects *all* elements on the page, yours or otherwise. Consider using [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to make default element styling consistent in a non-destructive manner.

```
.keys,
.top
```

For this app, this looks fine. Putting this on another page with existing markup, you can potentially clobber other styles (or get yours clobbered) because the class names are too generic. Also, very specific CSS (nested selectors) increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). CSS written like this isn't easy to override. Consider using [BEM](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) naming scheme instead. It allows you to construct low-specificity selectors as well as make them meaningful.

```
transition: all 0.2s ease;
```

Assuming you can CSS3 or don't care about older browsers. The problem with `all` is that it applies to `all`. If you happen to change another property which also happens to be transitionable, this can catch you off guard. Consider specifying the specific property to transition.

```
window.onload = function() {
```

Nothing wrong here. Just wanted to point out that `window.onload` is probably the very last event to fire during the page load process. It also fires only after all images have loaded, which can take very long. Consider usign [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead.

```
    clear.onclick = function() {
      result.innerHTML = '';
    };
```

One issue I see when doing handlers this way is that what if you want to add more handlers. Simply assigning a function to the event would only assign one at a time. In times where you want more handlers, this can be tricky. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

```
var numbers = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var result = document.querySelectorAll('.result')[0];
var clear = document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0];
```

`querySelectorAll` has a single-element counterpart: [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Use that for single-element returns. And while you're at it, you can forget the `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName`, use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` for consistency. Performance losses are negligible in this case.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
  if (numbers[i].innerHTML === '=') {
```

`=` isn't a number. You should probably remove it from the `numbers` collection to avoid complexity in the code. Treat it like your `clear`.

Also, consider converting `numbers` to a proper array. This is possible using `Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers)`. This way, you can easily use the `forEach` method to loop through the elements instead of constructing a fiddly `for` loop.

```
result.innerHTML = eval(result.innerHTML);
```

This can be tricky, not because `eval` is very powerful (that's a different issue), but because you're allowing execution of an arbitrary expression that may be interpretted very differently by JavaScript. One example is mentioned in the comments, where the numbers may be treated as octal. `011 + 2` isn't 13 but instead, `9 + 2` which is `11`.

Since you are not separating the numbers explicitly anywhere for us to use `parseFloat` on each one to get the correct number representation, consider building a simple expression parser.